# JPA updating entity including list of entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In general, my aim is to parse xml file into DB tables, so the file is something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Storage>
    <Box id="1">
        <Item id="1"/>
        <Item color="red" id="2"/>
        <Box id="3">
            <Item id="3" color="red" />
            <Item id="4" color="black" />
        </Box>
        <Box id="6"/>
        <Item id="5"/>
    </Box>
    <Item id="6"/>
</Storage>
```

I can parse it with umarshaller and it creates Storage object fine, but when trying to update boxes and items in db a problem emerges. Entites which I use look like this

```java
package com.demo.alpha.domen;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;


import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOX")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Box {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "CONTAINED IN")
    private int containedIn;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "box", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    private List<Item> items;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Box parentBox;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentBox", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @XmlElement(name = "Box")
    private List<Box> boxes;
}
```

```java
package com.demo.alpha.domen;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "COLOR")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "CONTAINED IN")
    private int containedIn;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTAINED_IN")
    private Box box;
}
```

And I'm not sure how should I map box including other boxes, because it's the same table, and I need CONTAINED_IN to be an id of parent box. When trying to update it with jpa repository get org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException in this query

```
   select
        box0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        box0_.contained in as containe2_0_1_,
        box0_.parent_box_id as parent_b3_0_1_,
        boxes1_.parent_box_id as parent_b3_0_3_,
        boxes1_.id as id1_0_3_,
        boxes1_.id as id1_0_0_,
        boxes1_.contained in as containe2_0_0_,
        boxes1_.parent_box_id as parent_b3_0_0_ 
    from
        box box0_ 
    left outer join
        box boxes1_ 
            on box0_.id=boxes1_.parent_box_id 
    where
        box0_.id=?
```

[starting log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ep3iKdkEkg6WNcyNnLflZRvXNJkJo0Vr)

Comment: Not sure I follow. You say that you 'need CONTAINED_IN to be an id of parent box', but you already have the parent box mapped by the property `parentBox`. Since there's no `@JoinColumn` on that field, a join column with a default name (i.e. `parent_box_id `) will be created for you

Comment: but where will it be created? and what will it join? it's the same BOX table where some boxes are inside other boxes

Comment: Logically, it will join two `Box`es. Physically, it will join one row in the `BOX` table with another. It will be created in the `BOX` table, of course (where else)? You can even see it being referenced in the generated query: `boxes1_.parent_box_id`, where `boxes1_` is an alias for the `BOX` table

Comment: so, CONTAINED_IN seems like redundant column? even so, it shouldn't cause all saving to fail, it'd be just null I suppose

Comment: It probably shouldn't. Please post the detailed error you're getting, together with the stack trace

Comment: ok, I added log